# If $x^3 \equiv x+1 \pmod 5$ then $x\equiv 2 \pmod 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I prove this?

I thought maybe try an exhaustive approach
For $x\equiv 0,1,3,4 \pmod 5$, it does not satisfy the equivalence, so $x\equiv 2$. I'm not sure if this is a correct method, but I think so since $x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4 \pmod 5$ are exhausive and disjoint cases.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I am not familiar with proving a result using exhaustion by proving that every other case does not satisfy. I have always dealt with showing that it exhaustively satisfies is the main confusion here

Comment: Well since $0,1,3,4$ don't satisfy the congruence then you're left to verify that $x\equiv 2\pmod{5}$ satisfies which is easy $2^3\equiv 8\equiv 3\equiv 2+1\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exhaustive approach is fine. You could factorize, writing $ x (x + 1) (x - 1) \equiv 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 5) $, and this immediately discounts the roots 1, -1, 0, so that you only need check 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $x(x^2 - 1) \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. We know that $x^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 5$. You can immediately discard $1$, as the LHS is $0$, then. For the same reason you can discard $0$ (you have $x \equiv 0 \pmod 5$). Therefore we have:

$$3x \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \iff x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe $x\not\equiv 0\mod 5$, so, using *Fermat*,
$$ (1)\enspace x^3\equiv x+1 \implies x^5\equiv x^3+x^2\implies (2)\enspace x\equiv x^3+x^2. $$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ imply $\; x^2\equiv -1\mod5$, and the square roots of $-1$ mod. $5$ are $2$ and $3$.

However, one checks $3$ is not a root of the given equation, while $2$ is.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x^3\equiv x+1\pmod5\iff x(x+1)(x-1)\equiv1\pmod5\\\text{FLT }\Rightarrow x^4=x(x^3)=x(x+1)\equiv 1\pmod5$$

Then$$\color{red}{x-1\equiv 1\pmod5}$$